# Can we create Two customers with same email (Magento 1)

Tags: customer, magento-1.4

I have just saw a different behaviour

I have created a customer with email "abc@abc.com" from admin.

& then tried to login from frontend but it asked to sign up i sign up & customer created.

Any thoughts if this is normal behavior in Magento 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two settings for this in Magento. You can either have customer accounts in website scope or in global scope. If you have it in global scope there can only be one unique email overall, if you have it set to website scope it can be one customer email per website.

System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Account Sharing Options

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, currently its set to "Per website" due to that 2 same email customer were created ?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible if they were created under different magento websites.